# List of functions references

Tags: c++, list, function, boost, reference

I'm using boost::function for making references to the functions. Can I make a list of references?
For example:

```
boost::function<bool (Entity &handle)> behaviorRef;
```

And I need in a list of such pointers. For example:

```
std::vector<behaviorRef> listPointers;
```

Of course it's wrong code due to behaviorRef isn't a type.

So the question is: how can I store a list of pointers for the function?

Comment: If they all share the same signature, what's wrong with a `typedef`? If you're looking for functions with different signatures though, some Boost guru must help, I'm not familiar with `boost::function`.

Comment: @Pieter: if the signatures are different, but compatible, `boost::function` will still help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
typedef boost::function<bool (Entity&)> behaviorRef_type;
std::vector<behaviorRef_type> listPointers;
```

Comment: Heh, I forgot about typedef. Thank you.

Comment: @Ockonal: I suppose `std::vector<bool (Entity&)>` would work, too, but a `typedef` is often better anyway. Never forget about such a useful tool in your toolbox.

Comment: Did you mean `std::vector<boost::function<bool(Entity&)>>`?

Comment: @Eric: Indeed. Damn. `<hangs_head_in_shame>`